# How to Cite research papers retrieved from a computer software?

Tags: research-process, citations, thesis

There's an offline school software from the computer laboratory which is able to view research paper from the previous students who had graduated. How should I cite it in my reference list using APA 6 Format if I used a paper from the software as my related literature?

Comment: Could you please clarify what _I found a thesis from a school software that contains all of their previous students research_ means? (You can edit your question, rather than respond below.)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you are using a certain piece of software that allows you to read papers. If this is the case, you can cite the paper just as you would if you had read it via another source (e.g. online, or even the print version). For example, it's not necessary to cite Google Chrome or Adobe Acrobat Reader every time you view a pdf using one of them.

Comment: but then if I had it from google I can provide links which in this case I can't since it's from an offline software

Comment: Why do you need to provide a link? A citation should include the author's name(s), paper title, venue and date of publication.